# @NamedStoredProcedureQuery is not working for the simple procedure call in JPA Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures, procedure

I am getting an error : *Attempt to set a parameter name that does not occur in the SQL: i_reorg_id* . It does not make sense to me as there is i_reorg_id in the SQL.

Procedure is:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRINTREORGID(i_reorg_id IN VARCHAR2, o_reorg_id OUT VARCHAR2)
AS BEGIN
  SELECT reorg_id
  INTO o_reorg_id
  FROM reorg_automation_workflowinput
  WHERE reorg_id = i_reorg_id;
END;
```

Entity is:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "fetchProcedure", procedureName = "PRINTREORGID", parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "i_reorg_id"),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "o_reorg_id"), 
                }) 
        })
```

And Repository is:

```
    @Procedure(name = "fetchProcedure", procedureName="PRINTREORGID")
    String reorgAutomationWorkFlow(@Param("i_reorg_id") String i_reorg_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can call the procedure another way(This is Best Practice):-**

**Procedure:-**

```
procedure getEmployeeById(
        id_in IN EMPLOYEE.ID%type,
        e_disp OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) IS
        hasEmployee number;
    BEGIN
        hasEmployee := 0;
        SELECT count(*) into hasEmployee from EMPLOYEE where ID = id_in;
        IF hasEmployee <> 0 THEN --here <> means !=
            OPEN e_disp FOR SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = id_in;
        ELSE
            --return empty SYS_REFCURSOR couse 1=2 not equal always
            OPEN e_disp FOR SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE 1=2;
        END IF;
    END getEmployeeById;
```

**Call From Java:-**
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inc8X.png)

Comment: I made modifications. Now I am getting error: Cannot mix positional parameter with named parameter registrations

Comment: Can you share your code or screenshot ?